# Knowing when GSM/CSD connection has broken

Tags: c++, gsm

**Background**

I have a GSM modem connected through a COM port. I open the COM port using `CreateFile` and I'm able to send various AT commands. I use `ATD` to place a CSD (data) call or `ATS0=1` to receive one.

**Now the problem**

How can I know that the connection has broken in the middle of a data call?

Actually, when a call is broken I get a `NO CARRIER` message. But the problem is GSM modem mixes the commands/notifications with the actual data. So How can I know if this message is part of the data itself, or it's in fact a call-broken message from the modem?

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CD signal (Carrier Detect) will turn off.  Named RLSD in GetCommModemStatus() and WaitCommEvent().  That's the moral equivalent of std::bad_alloc when you work with a modem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at it. By the way, is it __necessary__ to call `WaitCommEvent` before `GetCommModemStatus`? 

MSDN is a bit vague on this.

Comment: Erm, no, they are quite unrelated.  WaitCommEvent lets you do stuff asynchronously, GetCommModemStatus is the equivalent of polling.